# Making class useable as a Path or str in python open function

Tags: python

I have a custom `File` class. I want to be able to pass it to the built-in `open` function like this:

```
f = File('./example.txt')
with open(f, 'rb') as fh:
    # read content as usual
```

But this results in the error

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not File

The `File` class has a `__str__` method which returns a string that can be used with `open`, so this works for me:

```
with open(str(f), 'rb') as fh:
```

But I want to use `f` directly. I tried inheriting it from `Path` but could not figure it out. Is there a simple way to make this work?

Comment: Okay, so, let's read the error message: `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not File`. So those are the types you could in principle inherit from. `str` and `bytes` aren't really intended for subclassing, though; so maybe it would be a good idea to *read the documentation* for `os.PathLike` to understand what's going on? You have multiple gold badges and an account over 9 years old, so you should understand by now the [virtues of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an `os.PathLike` object by adding an `__fspath__` method that returns the path.

Example:

```
>>> class File:
...  def __fspath__(self):
...   return "C:\\temp"
...
>>> open(File())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\temp'
```

For more info, see the relevant [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.PathLike.__fspath__).